# Better way for sending data through socket

Tags: java, android, json, xml, sockets

I have android applicatoin which is sending location to server every 4 seconds, and than server send all locations from clients to every client. For server code I'm using java. I create object Position which have four variabls (username, time, latitude, longitude). I send this object to server on every update and than on server I save this in database.

Every 5 seconds I send all locations from server to every client. For every user I create object Position and all objects than send in ArrayList through socket to clients. My question is, if this is best approach, or whould be faster if data on server would be written into json or xml and than would be send to client.

Comment: Stop doing that.  There's no point to sending it every 4 seconds.  GPS only updates about once a minute.  Once every 30 seconds maximum.  You're wasting bandwidth and battery power.

Comment: I get location update every second if gps is on and if android device is moving.

Comment: No you don't.  Consumer hardware in phones doesn't update that fast.  You might have a provider that's calling you that fast (although if it is that's probably a bug) but you don't get new values that fast.

Comment: And honestly even if you did-  theres absolutely nothing your app is doing that's worth the cost to the client in bandwidth and battery power to update your server that frequently.

Comment: So how can you see your location in "realtime" when you are moving on google maps if you would get update every minute? I think you are wrong.

Comment: App will have option for how frequent updates will be...

Comment: I did pretty extensive testing a few years ago-  I wrote an app that constantly monitored position to determine speed and figure out if you were driving (based on your speed history).  Never saw any phone update more than once every 30 seconds.  Most devices were once per minute.

Answer (score 0):

1. JSON is better than XML because it takes less size so transfer
   the rate is faster.
2. Use WebSockets for periodic duplex connections.